# Trouble with opening a .res file

Tags: windows

I recently obtained some files with the extension of .res
The problem I am facing right now is that I am unable to open it using different kinds of Resource Editors. 
Here are the list of programs I have tried:

**Visual Studio 2017**

**ResourceHacker**

**Delphi Decompiler**

**XN Resource Editor**

And here is an example of the content of the file when opened in Notepad++: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrXo3.jpg

What could be the cause of me being unable to open this file? Am I missing anything?

Comment: You may want to open the files with a hex editor. Opening them with Notepad++ won't get you very far. But this does not look like a Windows resource file. Some other programs (games) also write files with a .res extension.

Comment: Why not ask the supplier of the file what it is?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I tried opening it in hex editor, but i can't make anything out of it. If a game creation software writes files to .res, is there any way to open and edit them?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan unfortunately, the company that created the program with all these files have gone kaput.

Comment: So you will need to reverse engineer it then. What are you waiting for? We can't help you do it. Not with this information. "I have a file. I don't know what is in it. What is in it?"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well sir, please forgive me as i'm new to this reverse engineering thing. I'm trying my best to understand what sort of programs may aid me to correctly interpret the file. Once I have a direction, I can work on it on my own. I can supply you a sample of the file right here: https://mega.nz/#!OcNxkYoT!5XUQITmY-0SGRHWB1r_A8SzMAp33prFiHPtfQ5e-RPg

Comment: Use a hex editor

Comment: I looked at the file you linked to. Impossible to tell what it contains, or what its format is, especially if you don't even know what the file ought to contain. The few human-readable strings in the file don't ring a bell.

Answer (score -1):

`.res` files are to `.rc` files like `.obj.` or `.lib` files to `.cpp` files - they are the **compiled** version of the resource definition files.

Don't expect that file to be editable by the likes of Notepad, treat it as any other compiled *binary* file. Especially since it really **is** a compiled binary file.

Having said that - when you "import" that file for use in your app you need to explicitly specify it in the list of "import libraries" (unlike a `.lib` file which the linker could infer from the list of dependencies). At least that is the case with MSVC++ 2015 (haven't tried it on 2017 yet)

Comment: Not these. AFAICT, these are not compiled Windows resource files. And a compiled Windows resource (.res) file can be opened by one of the programs mentioned in the question.

Comment: Not sure what you tried but as a sanity check I have *just* opened 3 of the many `.res` files I have in my build directories and they are all (expectedly) binary. Any chance you are talking about `.rc2` files? Those are text (though UNICODE, just like `.rc`)

Comment: The files in the question (he posted a sample) are files with a `.res` extension, but they are NOT WIndows resource files. That is why the OP can't open them with a resource editor. I know that Windows `.res` files are binary, but these can usually be opened with a proper resource editor, like the ones he mentions. The `.res`files on your hard disk are Windows resource files, so that you can open them doesn't mean a lot to him. Note that files with a `.res` extension do not have to be resource files. Anyone can use that extension.